# Convert flat XML table data where elements are concatenated row and column names into nested XML, using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xmltable

I have XML output representing a table of data being output like this:

```
<results>
  <Row1.Name>Henry</Row1.Name>
  <Row1.Id>P162</Row1.Id>
  <Row1.Age>23</Row1.Age>
  <Row2.Name>John</Row2.Name>
  <Row2.Id>P137</Row2.Id>
  <Row2.Age>27</Row2.Age>
  <Row3.Name>Mary</Row3.Name>
  <Row3.Id>L493</Row3.Id>
  <Row3.Age>32</Row3.Age>
</results>
```

and I want to convert it to this:

```
<results>
  <Row>
    <Name>Henry</Name>
    <Id>P162<Id>
    <Age>23</Age>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Id>P137<Id>
    <Age>27</Age>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Name>Mary</Name>
    <Id>L493<Id>
    <Age>32</Age>
  </Row>
</results>
```

The application I am working with forces me to use XSLT 1.0, and I'm sure this is really simple, but I'm having a mental block today so I figured I'd ask my virtual colleagues.

Anybody got any ideas?

NOTE:  Amended the desired output to not show iterative row numbers, which is what I want.

Haven't got anything close to working yet.  Still playing around with different things.

Thought I could write something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="Row" select="distinct-values(*[contains(name(),'Row')])" />
           <xsl:for-each select="$Row">
               <xsl:variable name="rowName" select="name()" />
               <Row>
                   <xsl:for-each select="*[contains(name(),$Row)]">
                       <xsl:copy select="." />
                   </xsl:for-each>
               </Row>
           </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to produce this:

```
<results>
    <Row>
        <Row1.Name>Henry</Row1.Name>
        <Row1.Id>P162</Row1.Id>
        <Row1.Age>23</Row1.Age>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Row2.Name>John</Row2.Name>
        <Row2.Id>P137</Row2.Id>
        <Row2.Age>27</Row2.Age>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Row3.Name>Mary</Row3.Name>
        <Row3.Id>L493</Row3.Id>
        <Row3.Age>32</Row3.Age>
   </Row>
</results>
```

and then go back  and remove all the Row# prefixes with:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*[contains(name(),'.')]">
        <xsl:variable name="Name" select="substring-after(name(),'.')" />
        <xsl:element name="{$Name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Neither transform works though and I don't think I can use `distinct-values` with XSLT 1.0

Comment: Can you update your question to show us what you've tried with XSL? We might be able to offer a simple change to your current XSL rather than us coming up with the entire XSL ourselves. You'll find that you will tend to get more and better answers that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a grouping problem, and the standard approach to such problems in XSLT 1.0 is called *Muenchian grouping*.  You define a key that groups your elements in the way you want and then use a trick with `generate-id` to process just one element per group.  In this case you want to group elements by the part of their name before the dot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:key name="elementByRow" match="/*/*"
           use="substring-before(name(), '.')" />

  <xsl:template match="/results">
    <results>
      <!-- pick out the first RowN.* element for each N -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[generate-id() =
         generate-id(key('elementByRow', substring-before(name(), '.'))[1])]" />
    </results>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <Row>
      <!-- process _all_ the elements that belong to this row -->
      <xsl:for-each select="key('elementByRow', substring-before(name(), '.'))">
        <xsl:element name="{substring-after(name(), '.')}">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Row>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @user2960730 glad it worked, and thanks for fixing my typo too. If your problem is now solved you might consider _accepting_ this answer by clicking on the tick mark to the left. As well as being the way to reward people for helping you, it shows others at a glance that the problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry, I forgot that.  :)